# My php Form doesn't add messages to PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, forms

So I've updated the code below but it still doesn't work and I don't understand why... The messages doesn't appear in my database in PhpMyAdmin and I don't see the error messages I've put when for example a entry in my form is empty.. Thank you in advance for helping me.........................................................................................................................................................................................

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=portfolio', 
    'root', 
    '',
    array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING, 
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8' 
    )
);

$message = '';

if (!empty($_POST))
{
   //Contrôle des données :
   if (!isset($_POST['nom']) || strlen($_POST['nom']) < 3 || strlen($_POST['nom']) > 50)
   {
      $message .= '<div>Le champ "nom" doit comporter entre 3 et 20 caractères.</div>';
   }

   if (!isset($_POST['prenom']) || strlen($_POST['prenom']) < 3 || strlen($_POST['prenom']) > 50)
   {
      $message .= '<div>Le champ "prénom" doit comporter entre 2 et 20 caractères.</div>';
   }

   if (!isset($_POST['email']) || strlen($_POST['email'] > 50) || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    {
        $message .= '<div class="alert alert-danger">L\'email n\'est pas valide</div>'; 
    }

   if(!isset($_POST) || !preg_match('#^[0-9]{10}$#', $_POST['telephone']) )
    {
        $message .= '<div class="alert alert-danger">Le champ "téléphone" doit comporter 10 chiffres</div>';
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['sujet']) || strlen($_POST['sujet']) < 3 || strlen($_POST['sujet']) > 100)
    {
       $message .= '<div>Le champ "sujet" doit comporter entre 2 et 20 caractères.</div>';
    }

    if(!isset($_POST['message']) || strlen($_POST['message']) < 3 || strlen($_POST['message']) > 500 )
    {
        $message .= '<div class="alert alert-danger">Le message est trop long !</div>';
    }

    if(empty($message))
    {
        foreach ($_POST as $indice => $valeur) {
            $_POST[$indice] = htmlspecialchars($valeur, ENT_QUOTES);  
        }
        
        $resultat = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO message(nom, prenom, email, telephone, sujet, message) VALUES(:nom, :prenom, :email, :telephone, :sujet, :message)");
        
        $succes = $resultat->execute(array(
            ':nom' => $_POST['nom'],
            ':prenom' => $_POST['prenom'],
            ':email' => $_POST['email'],
            ':telephone' => $_POST['telephone'],
            ':sujet' => $_POST['sujet'], 
            ':message' => $_POST['message']
        ));

        if ($succes)
        {
            $message .= '<div>Le message a bien été envoyé !</div>';
        }
        else 
        {
            $message .= '<div>Une erreur est survenue...</div>';
        }
    
    }// if (empty($message))

}//if (!empty($_POST))

<form action="" method="post" class="container form-container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <input id="nom" name="nom" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?= $_POST['nom'] ?? '';?>" placeholder="Nom">
        <input id="prenom" name="prenom" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?= $_POST['prenom'] ?? '';?>" placeholder="Prénom">
        <input id="email" name= "email" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?= $_POST['email'] ?? '';?>"placeholder="Email">
        <input id="telephone" name="telephone" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?= $_POST['telephone'] ?? '';?>"placeholder="Téléphone">
        <input id="sujet" name="sujet" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?= $_POST['sujet'] ?? '';?>"placeholder="Sujet">
        <textarea id="message"  name="message" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10" value=""placeholder="Votre message"><?= $_POST['message'] ?? '';?></textarea>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Envoyer">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked what `$_POST` contains? Whether MySQL returns any error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name attributes are missing in your form - so nothing gests postet.

It should be:

**UPDATED 4.1.2020 19:03 CET
textarea was wrong,  sujet vs subject! **

```
<form action="" method="post" class="container form-container">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <input id="nom" name="nom" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?= $_POST['nom'] ?? '';?>" placeholder="Nom">
    <input id="prenom" name="prenom" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?= $_POST['prenom'] ?? '';?>" placeholder="Prénom">
    <input id="email" name= "email" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?= $_POST['email'] ?? '';?>"placeholder="Email">
    <input id="telephone" name="telephone" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?= $_POST['telephone'] ?? '';?>"placeholder="Téléphone">   
    <input id="sujet" name="sujet" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?= $_POST['sujet'] ?? '';?>"placeholder="Sujet">     
    <textarea id="message"  name="message" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10" value=""placeholder="Votre message"><?= $_POST['message'] ?? '';?></textarea>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Envoyer">
</div>
```

Additionally this is wrong

setting a variable first then asking for its content is not very useful ;-)
additionally this variable IS NOT SET ANYWHERE ELSE?!?

```
 $succes = ''; //   delete this line and set the variable above in the script 
     if ($succes) 
     {
     $message .= '<div>Le message a bien été envoyé !</div>';
    }
    else 
  {
  $message .= '<div>Une erreur est survenue...</div>';
 }
```

so it should be
you have to assign a value to succes - for example if you want to check the insert:

```
    $succes= $resultat->execute(array(
        ':nom' => $_POST['nom'],
        ':prenom' => $_POST['prenom'],
        ':email' => $_POST['email'],
        ':telephone' => $_POST['telephone'],
        ':sujet' => $_POST['sujet'], 
        ':message' => $_POST['message']
    ));



    //$succes = '';   // NO!  
    //do not  just **write $var='';** when you get a variable is undefined error
    if ($succes) 
    {
        $message .= '<div>Le message a bien été envoyé !</div>';
    }
    else 
    {
        $message .= '<div>Une erreur est survenue...</div>';
    }
```

I also think that the last if condition is wrong and should be like this:
It cannot be EMPTY AND larger than 500 chars ;-) and the ['message'] was missing in the first condition

```
if(empty($_POST['message']) || strlen($_POST['message']) < 3 || strlen($_POST['message']) > 500 )
    {
        $message .= '<div class="alert alert-danger">Le message est trop long !</div>';
    }
```

###############################################################################
FINAL UPATE: here is the complete fixed code with some debug additions

```
<?php


$pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=portfolio', 
    'root', 
    '',
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8' 
    )
);

$message = '';

if (!empty($_POST))
{
    
   //Contrôle des données :
   if (!isset($_POST['nom']) || strlen($_POST['nom']) < 3 || strlen($_POST['nom']) > 50)
   {
      $message .= '<div>Le champ "nom" doit comporter entre 3 et 20 caractères.</div>';
   }

   if (!isset($_POST['prenom']) || strlen($_POST['prenom']) < 3 || strlen($_POST['prenom']) > 50)
   {
      $message .= '<div>Le champ "prénom" doit comporter entre 2 et 20 caractères.</div>';
   }

   if (!isset($_POST['email']) || strlen($_POST['email'] > 50) || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    {
        $message .= '<div class="alert alert-danger">L\'email n\'est pas valide</div>'; 
    }

   if(!isset($_POST) || !preg_match('#^[0-9]{10}$#', $_POST['telephone']) )
    {
        $message .= '<div class="alert alert-danger">Le champ "téléphone" doit comporter 10 chiffres</div>';
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['sujet']) || strlen($_POST['sujet']) < 3 || strlen($_POST['sujet']) > 100)
    {
       $message .= '<div>Le champ "sujet" doit comporter entre 2 et 20 caractères.</div>';
    }

    if(!isset($_POST['message']) || strlen($_POST['message']) < 3 || strlen($_POST['message']) > 500 )
    {
        $message .= '<div class="alert alert-danger">Le message est trop long !</div>';
    }

    
    if(empty($message))
    { //echo"<br>message empty<br>";
     
        foreach ($_POST as $indice => $valeur) {
            $_POST[$indice] = htmlspecialchars($valeur, ENT_QUOTES);  
        }
        
        $resultat = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO messages(nom, prenom, email, telephone, sujet, message) VALUES(:nom, :prenom, :email, :telephone, :sujet, :message)");
        
        
        if (!$resultat)
        { $message .= var_dump($resultat->errorInfo());}
     else{ $message .= "PDO prepare sucessful";}
        
     //var_dump($_POST);
              
        $succes = $resultat->execute(array(
            ':nom' => $_POST['nom'],
            ':prenom' => $_POST['prenom'],
            ':email' => $_POST['email'],
            ':telephone' => $_POST['telephone'],
            ':sujet' => $_POST['sujet'], 
            ':message' => $_POST['message']
        ));
        
        

        
     
        //changed for debug 
        if ($succes)
        {
        $message .='<div>Le message a bien été envoyé !</div>';
        $message .= "PDO execute sucessful<br>";}
        
        else 
        {
        $message .= '<div>Une erreur est survenue...</div>';
        $message .= var_dump($resultat->errorInfo()); //for debug only 
        }
        
     
    echo "MESSAGE saved!<br>". $message;
    }
    else     
    { echo "ERROR: ". $message;
    }
}


if (empty($_POST))
{
?>
<form action="" method="post" class="container form-container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <input id="nom" name="nom" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['nom'] ?? '';?>" placeholder="Nom">
        <input id="prenom" name="prenom" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['prenom'] ?? '';?>" placeholder="Prénom">
        <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['email'] ?? '';?>"placeholder="Email">
        <input id="telephone" name="telephone" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['telephone'] ?? '';?>"placeholder="Téléphone">
        <input id="sujet" name="sujet" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['sujet'] ?? '';?>" placeholder="Sujet">
        <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10" value=""placeholder="Votre message"><?php echo $_POST['message'] ?? '';?></textarea>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Envoyer">
    </div>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: If the anwer helped you please mark the answer as "accepted".

Comment: Thank you ! I forgot this. but it still doesn't work ,I don't understand...

Comment: I DO understand why.  ;-) 

You have a condition   **if sucess**  but sucess  IS NOT SET ANYWHERE above

Comment: I have changed my answer to reflect the comments above ..

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew I had to assign the succes value but forgot Unfortunately, It still doesn't work, All my code seems to be good, however nothing appears in my database, and if a input is empty I don't succeed to see the error messages I've put.. It should works now,I don't know where can be the errors ?

Comment: @alexeusebio Please update your original question and copy the current code into it.

Comment: i found a few  errors in the code .. and updated them above

Comment: Yes thank you I've seen it, I've updated my original question but there is still a problem somewhere...

Comment: please be **more specific**   please specify 'a problem'  more detailed. What is the problem? What is happening or NOT happening?   ...

Comment: This line is still wrong!     '´<textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10" value="<?php echo $_POST['message'] ?? '';?>"placeholder="Votre message"></textarea> ´' please take teh version from my answer

Comment: Thank you very very much, finally It works now :) I can see the messages. But ... I have to find now why the errors alert are still not displayed when an entry is empty or why the message of succes that indicate the message is well sent doesn't display...

Comment: I updated the answer with a completely revised version, where also the database preparation is checked. if there is a problem in the preparation of the PDO statment it did not display anything in the past.  (this cost me 1h as i had set sujet in my test database to integer and not varchar   :-P  and no error was displayed - and not even  shown in the log :-/ )  This version also has a correct message output if it was successful or not  so   ----  remark: **ARE YOU SURE** that all phone numbers of your clients have 10 digits??? (defi in the regexp)  here the phone numbers can have ANY length!

Comment: _But ... I have to find now why the errors alert are still not displayed when an entry is empty or why the message of succes that indicate the message is well sent doesn't display_   **BECAUSE** you did not echo the $message anywhere :-B      ------- **please mark my answer as accepted**  .

Comment: yes indeed ^^Thank you for the help and patience

Comment: Happy to hear that it finally works  :-)   Pleease remove the  $message .= var_dump($resultat->errorInfo());   on production sites or do something like if $debug=1 {...}

Comment: Yes, thaanks ;)